# Windows 7 wont connect to shared folders

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, passwords, username

I'm going to quote something right from the beginning, this does not work:

> To configure NTLM compatibility for Windows Vista or Windows 7
>
> 1 Click Start > All Programs > Accessories > Run and type secpol.msc in the
>   Open box, and then click OK.
>
> 2 Click Local Policies > Security Options > Network Security: LAN Manager
>   authentication level.
>
> 3 Click SendLM& NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated.
>
> 4 Click Apply.

This is the situation, from OSX/Linux I can see and connect to all computers on the network.

On This windows 7 computer, everytime I try to connect to the network I get 'bad username or password'

I have tried almost every combination of the above to try and get things working to no joy.  I've tried turning off 128bit authentication, tried doing it from a new user account and a myriad of other things.

Here is the kicker,  I can install a virtual instance on this same computer, using vmware - use the same credentials I use for this computer.. and network works perfectly.  The settings for the instanced install are practically out the box.

I have avast antivirus installed but currently it's turned completely off.

Does anyone have experience of this?  if I type \server or \ipaddress into explorer I do get the authentication prompt, however it repeatedly asks for the login details.  I do see the other computers in the network.

Thanks for any assistance!!

Aug 14 07:34:58 4development.com digest-service[1902]: digest-request: uid=0
Aug 14 07:34:58 4development.com digest-service[1902]: digest-request: init request
Aug 14 07:34:58 4development.com digest-service[1902]: digest-request: init return domain: LOCUTUS server: 4DEVELOPMENT indomain was: 
Aug 14 07:34:58 4development.com digest-service[1902]: digest-request: uid=0
Aug 14 07:34:58 4development.com digest-service[1902]: digest-request: od failed with 2 proto=ntlmv2
Aug 14 07:34:58 4development.com digest-service[1902]: digest-request: user=JUPITER-VMWARE7\ian
Aug 14 07:34:58 4development.com digest-service[1902]: digest-request kdc: ok user=LOCUTUS\ian proto=ntlmv2 flags: ENC_128, NEG_VERSION, NEG_TARGET_INFO, NEG_NTLM, NEG_SIGN, NEG_TARGET, NEG_UNICODE

That's the log from the successful login, the following is from the failed one:

Aug 14 07:38:03 4development.com digest-service[2019]: digest-request: uid=0
Aug 14 07:38:03 4development.com digest-service[2019]: digest-request: od failed with 2 proto=ntlmv1
Aug 14 07:38:03 4development.com digest-service[2019]: digest-request: user=JUPITER\ian
Aug 14 07:38:03 4development.com digest-service[2019]: digest-request: kdc failed with -1561745600 proto=ntlmv1
Aug 14 07:38:03 4development.com digest-service[2019]: digest-request: guest failed with -1561745590 proto=ntlmv1
Aug 14 07:38:04 4development.com digest-service[2019]: digest-request: uid=0
Aug 14 07:38:04 4development.com digest-service[2019]: digest-request: init request
Aug 14 07:38:04 4development.com digest-service[2019]: digest-request: init return domain: LOCUTUS server: 4DEVELOPMENT indomain was: 
Aug 14 07:38:04 4development.com digest-service[2019]: digest-request: uid=0
Aug 14 07:38:04 4development.com digest-service[2019]: digest-request: init request
Aug 14 07:38:04 4development.com digest-service[2019]: digest-request: init return domain: LOCUTUS server: 4DEVELOPMENT indomain was:

Comment: This is very weird first of all I just happened to do a google search and found your guys suggestions. - I still see nothing on superuser.com

Comment: Secondly....  I guess I should clear up a few things. I finally gave up and reinstalled win 7 and then discovered that now both the main machine and the vm do the same thing.   To fix I reverted the quoted above and it all spun into life.  I •know• I double checked and triple checked the comparisons on secpol.

Comment: Lastly, having reset the ntlm settings I can now access 4development.com however I can't get into my /music share. In windows it shows as read only but in osx it looks like any other folder and I have the media repo drive shared completely.   This is the other thing, I'm using osx 10.10 Yosemite server which uses smb3.  As I said everything else works fine but the music folder which contains 15k+ songs, in osx if I copy a chunk of folders out I can suddenly see the folder but if I create 2 folders and drop enough in - neither the new folder or the music folder open -  any ideas?